# watch tail -20 ls -ltr?

Tags: ls, watch

I would like to see the latest content of a directory.

I tried **watch tail -20 ls -ltr ./{directory}** it is not working.

Is there a way to constantly shows the content of a directory like watch command?

Comment: First ask yourself, how would you look at the latest content of a directory just as a one-off, _without_ using `watch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the directory list first (`ls`), then limit it (`tail`) and `watch` the whole thing:

```
watch "ls -ltr ./ | tail -20"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know it's a newbie question what does | do or mean in Unix command?

Comment: A unix pipe (not to be confused with a unix socket) means "connect the output of the left side to the input of the right side". It's part of the basic unix philosophy and it turns out to be very powerful for processing. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKzonnwoR2I